# windows 10 default wireless instead of ethernet

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

I have a Windows 10 machine that's both connected to wifi and ethernet (eth is for wake on lan purposes only). Problem is, windows always preselects the wired connection at boot. I tried changing the interface metric (wired to 1000, wifi to 10), but windows is still keeping the default wired. Is there anything else that I can do to get this going?

Comment: Your metric numbers are switched so Windows is doing exactly what you told it to do, to prefer the wireless connection, over the LAN connection

Comment: You also have non-sensical values, based on the documents I read, https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/299540/an-explanation-of-the-automatic-metric-feature-for-ipv4-routes a value of 1000 is meaningless basically

Comment: Use values of 5 and 25; 5 for the LAN and 25 for the WLAN

Comment: @Ramhound: I have read the question, and it appears to me that Windows is ***NOT*** doing exactly what the OP told it to do; it is ***NOT*** preferring the wireless connection over the Ethernet connection. The OP says that Windows always selects the wired connection at boot, even though he wants it to use wireless instead of Ethernet.

Comment: @G-Man It's not working because the author is using invalid metric values

Comment: @Ramhound: So why not say it as an answer?

Comment: I eventually figured it out. First of all setting the LOWER value gives HIGHER priority to the interface, so it should be 25 for the WLAN and 5 for the LAN, not the other way around. second, i also had to do this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking/windows-10-not-connect-to-wifi-automatically-when/0cda7a70-6e1d-4ed9-a370-41581970ba73